# Do I add both www and no-www for my Domain in Google webmaster tools?

Tags: google-search-console, no-www

When register my site to Google webmaster tools, which one should I register?

1. `mydomain.com`
2. `www.mydomain.com`
3. `Both?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are serving the same content under both domain names and you do not have the option to redirect (301/permanent) visitors who land at the non-canonical domain over to your canonical domain, you should register **both** domains at Webmaster Tools and then [set your preferred domain](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231).

Answer (score 1):

I registered mine with www. I suppose there isn't much of a difference between them. Using www.yourdomain.com or yourdomain.com is just a different referral of the A-record, but resolves the same host IP.

Answer (score 0):

You must register both. It will help you to verify your preferred domain and also will help to monitor both domains.